# usb_modeswitch error Huwaei E3372 4g Modem

Tags: modem

I tried following this tutorial to change mode of my Huwaei E3372 modem https://blog.unixweb.de/usb-stick-lte-telekom-magenta-eins-huawei-e398-modem-raspberry-pi/

System Raspberry 3B+
OS: Raspbian Stretch

But when i run:

```
usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -M '5553424312345678000000000000001106200000010000000000000000000000'
```

I get following error:

```
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 004 on bus 001
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 8
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
     Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
  Serial No.: 0123456789ABCDEF
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
 No active driver found. Detached before or never attached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response reading failed (error -9)
 Device is gone, skip any further commands
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

If i run lsusb, The mode is still mass storage mode

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem (Mass Storage Mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```